# Beamer Frame is fine in Standalone class, but header missing when main is compiled

Tags: standalone

I am able to compile the subfile perfectly well, but the main file deletes the header of the frame. Here is the `standalone` code:

```
    \documentclass[beamer]{standalone}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{standaloneframe}\frametitle{Last week we looked at:}
    \uncover<+-|alert@+>{
    }
    \end{standaloneframe}

    \end{document}
```

I have also tried without the `\frametitle` command, and that didn't change anything. In the following, the file "Overview" is the above subfile.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{standalone}
    \begin{document}
    \input{Overview}
    \end{document}
```

In fact the situation is worse than I thought. With the above code, it is now not compiling any pages at all. When I put the following code:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{standalone}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \input{Overview}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

it works, but then this would mean I needed a different `standalone` file for each slide.

Comment: docmute seems to work without any problems.

Comment: Why don't you use `frame` instead of `standaloneframe` in the standalone document.